# Mean of the syntax $.[custom name] in jquery

Tags: jquery

when i coding web app, i saw some jquery plugin define like this:

ex:

```
$.popmenu = function(element, options){
    this.element = $(element);
    this.settings = $.extend(true, $.popmenu.defaults, options);
    this.init();
};
```

I want to know what means of the syntax '$.popmenu' in jquery.
I have search but cannot find the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that they're adding the `popmenu` property to the jQuery function (`jQuery`, usually aliased as `$` as well). That means later they can call it via `$.popmenu`.

There are two styles of jQuery plugins: Ones which are meant to be called on jQuery *instances*, and ones that are called without an instance. This is an example of the second kind. (The first kind are created by adding to `$.fn`.)

Comment: Please give me an example on the second kind. I knew that the first kind i just use $(selector).[custom name] but on second kind when i debug it does not work like the first one.